# Getting cookie value as integer

Tags: javascript, cookies

The main problem is that when printing the cookie value it adds quotes around it, but in my case I need it to print is as a number not string.

Here is the function:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + '=';
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

For example, let's say, that before the Get cookie, I've set a cookie like with this:

```
function setCookie(cname, value) {
        document.cookie = cname + '=' + value + ';' + ';path=/';
    }
    setCookie('PirkumsVeikts', 'True');

setCookie(testCookie, 123);
```

and then I run the getCookie();

```
getCookie('testCookie')
```

It will print "123", but I need it to print it without the double quotes, is this possible?

Comment: `var test = Number(getCookie('testCookie'));`

Comment: Use the Number() function to convert from a string to an number, parsInt() would also work

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

`var cookie_value_as_int = parseInt(getCookie('testCookie'));`

Answer (score 0):

The cookie that you are returning is simply a string:

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + '=';
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return '';
}

function setCookie(cname, value) {
  document.cookie = cname + '=' + value + ';' + ';path=/';
}

setCookie('testCookie', 123);
console.log(getCookie('testCookie'));
```

If need be, you can simply convert this into a number by either casting it as one with [**`Number()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```
Number(getCookie('testCookie'));
```

Or parsing it as one with [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
parseInt(getCookie('testCookie'));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: If using `parseInt`, you should also specify the base denomination. `parseInt(getCookie('testCookie'), 10)`

Comment: Yep, I'd recommend specifying the radix as well to prevent confusion. I've personally never encountered a situation where it doesn't **default** to 10, but apparently such a situation can exist, so it helps to be be precise :)

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the value return to integer using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var number = parseInt(getCookie('testCookie'));
```